# Google maps js api, как изменить зуммер после инициализации карты?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Google maps js api, как изменить зуммер после инициализации карты ?

```
var options = {
          center: centerOfMap, // Set center.
          zoom: 7 // The zoom value.
};
     
// Create the map object.
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
```

Comment: Язык - вы сайт перепутали.

Comment: да                                   ................................................................

Comment: Google maps js api, как изменить зуммер после инициализации карты ?

Comment: На сайте есть кнопка "править" вы можете сами поправить ваш вопрос, а текст, после кнопки "править" можно скопировать и вставить на en-so (возможно там ответят быстрее).